# I've accidently pushed to a git repo with the wrong user account. How can I undo it or change the user?

Tags: git, github

I have just updated a repo on github https://github.com/christill89/instaslider and my computer was signed in with the wrong github account details. Now the latest two commits have been authored by the wrong account.

Is there a way I can either change the author or undo the last two commits and push again with the correct account?

The repo and code is correct, it's just authored by the wrong account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use patch files to modify the author (in the ${editor} step update the author):

```
git format-patch -2
git reset --hard HEAD~2
${editor} *.patch
git am *.patch
```

Then push with force to rewrite commit history:

```
git push -f
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be with this command:

```
git rebase -i -x "git commit --amend --author=\"New Author <someone@email.com>\"" HEAD~2
```

An editor will open where you can change the action to be taken for the commits. Just leave it the way it is (i.e. `pick`) and close the editor. The editor will open again for each of the two commits. You can edit the commit message if you want, then just close it again.

After the rebase process is complete, make sure the author is now right in your local history. Then use `git push -f origin <branchname>` to force-update the remote reference for your branch.